# Python - finding all possible grouping of elements in a list

Tags: python, list, grouping

I am trying to find a nice Pythonic way for finding all possible combinations of splitting a list into two groups, as in the following example:

```
my_array = [A,B,C]
```

The output should be:

```
[[[A],[B]]
[[A],[B,C]]
[[A],[C]]
[[A,B],[C]]
[[A,C],[B]]
[[B],[A]]
[[B],[A,C]]
[[B],[C]]
[[B,C],[A]]
[[C],[A]]
[[C],[A,B]]
[[C],[B]]]
```

Thanks!

Comment: Have you already found a not-so-nice-pythonic way for doing it?

Comment: In some of your exmaple you don't split the list. You throw off list elements.

Comment: Am working on it, but I thought there might be some built-in itertools-style function.

Comment: Yes, I know @Psytho. This is intentional. These might be valid combinations in my case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe this is what you need:

```
import itertools

my_array = ['A','B','C']

combos = []

for i in range(1,len(my_array)):
    combos += itertools.combinations(my_array, i)

result = []

for c1 in combos:
    curr = list(c1)
    for c2 in combos:
        if not any(i in curr for i in c2):
            result.append([curr, list(c2)])
result
#[[['A'], ['B']],
# [['A'], ['C']],
# [['A'], ['B', 'C']],
# [['B'], ['A']],
# [['B'], ['C']],
# [['B'], ['A', 'C']],
# [['C'], ['A']],
# [['C'], ['B']],
# [['C'], ['A', 'B']],
# [['A', 'B'], ['C']],
# [['A', 'C'], ['B']],
# [['B', 'C'], ['A']]]
```

Comment: That perfect @zipa, thanks. But, can I extend my questions? How about a case in which I`d need more than 2 groupings? 
For example, in case I have more than 3 elements in a list ([A,B,C,D,E']), more groping combinations are possible. ([[A],[B]], is one kind of grouping, but also [[A,B], [C,D],[E]])?

Comment: I have - it only divides it into two groups.

Comment: @Yair your edit creates another question, that requires a different algorithm. Maybe you can ask again instead if editing?

Comment: I did  - found at <https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50248453/grouping-combinations-in-python?noredirect=1#comment87515541_50248453>